# How to set facebook open graph meta tags in a symfony 1.4 site

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I regret using symfony, because the simplest things are so difficult to do.

How can I set facebook meta tags such as    in my layout.php file.

I've tried quiet a few things.

I know setting a title is as easy as this, but setting these meta tags is proving a challenge.

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setTitle('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

With just a deeper look into the code, I was able to find out that it's easier than I thought.

The documentation on this is rather lacking.

$response->addMeta("og:type","musician");